# Panel (Frame) size in Visual Studio Code (VSCode)

Tags: visual-studio-code, tab-size

There are extensions in Visual Studio Code, which open a tab/panel/frame (sorry I don't know the right term) on a side. For example if the code for a web page is in the left tab, then on the right it shows the rendered page in a browser.
What I need is the option to show (in real time) the size (in pixels) and the zoom (in percent) of that tab/panel. Like this here:
[image]

or similar to the Responsive Design Mode in a browser Web Developer tools - one could see the user window size in real time also when resizing it with the mouse.

There is an extension called Live Frame (jevakallio.vscode-live-frame), which allows to change the name of the panel through an option in the configuration file. I thought I could set this name to a vscode setting like `workbench.editor.?SomeTab?.?width?`.
Is this possible? Would it be refreshed in real time and what would be the setting name?

Any info on the topic - get/set tab/panel size in pixel, what are the vscode setting names would be much appreciated.